# Xamarin.Forms Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, fatal-error, segmentation-fault

My Android app crashes on Startup. This only happens sometimes (every 3rd or 4th execution).
I'm executing app on Device with Android OS 4.1.2 and App's minimum API is set at 15.
I've see many posts similar to this, but all with different solutions. Can someone figure out what's the problem?

```
09-02 17:16:08.158 I/dalvikvm(11108): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted global reference 0x1d600b72
09-02 17:16:08.158 E/dalvikvm(11108): VM aborting
09-02 17:16:08.158 E/mono-rt (11108): Stacktrace:
09-02 17:16:08.158 E/mono-rt (11108): 
09-02 17:16:08.158 E/mono-rt (11108):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
09-02 17:16:08.158 E/mono-rt (11108):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.wrapper_native_0x40bbb311 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) <IL 0x00030, 0xffffffff>
09-02 17:16:08.158 E/mono-rt (11108):   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr_JValue* (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) <IL 0x00070, 0xffffffff>
09-02 17:16:08.158 E/mono-rt (11108):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x00060] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1025
09-02 17:16:08.158 E/mono-rt (11108):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:306
09-02 17:16:08.158 E/mono-rt (11108):   at Android.OS.Handler..ctor (Android.OS.Looper) [0x000c5] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.OS.Handler.cs:195
09-02 17:16:08.158 E/mono-rt (11108):   at Android.App.SyncContext.Post (System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback,object) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:17
09-02 17:16:08.159 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction (object) <IL 0x00018, 0x000a3>
09-02 17:16:08.159 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback (System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,System.Threading.Tasks.Task&) <IL 0x00019, 0x00127>
09-02 17:16:08.159 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.Run (System.Threading.Tasks.Task,bool) <IL 0x0003d, 0x0017b>
09-02 17:16:08.159 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations () <IL 0x00090, 0x005c3>
09-02 17:16:08.159 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree () <IL 0x00046, 0x0013b>
09-02 17:16:08.159 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult (TResult) <IL 0x00059, 0x00213>
09-02 17:16:08.159 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult (TResult) <IL 0x00021, 0x00143>
09-02 17:16:08.159 E/mono-rt (11108):   at PCLStorage.FileSystemFolder/<CreateFileAsync>d__0.MoveNext () <IL 0x0023f, 0x00e1f>
09-02 17:16:08.159 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore/MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x000ff>
09-02 17:16:08.159 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) <IL 0x00029, 0x00177>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <IL 0x00003, 0x00057>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore/MoveNextRunner.Run () <IL 0x00049, 0x001c7>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () <IL 0x00013, 0x000b7>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () <IL 0x00017, 0x000f7>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback (object) <IL 0x00008, 0x00097>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) <IL 0x00029, 0x00177>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <IL 0x00003, 0x00057>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task&) <IL 0x00063, 0x0032b>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry (bool) <IL 0x00075, 0x0027f>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <IL 0x00002, 0x00047>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.<UnsafeQueueCustomWorkItem>m__0 (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x000ff>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108):   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00062, 0xffffffff>
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108): 
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108): Attempting native Android stacktrace:
09-02 17:16:08.160 E/mono-rt (11108): 
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108):   at dvmAbort+75 [0x40bb5a38]
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108):   at IndirectRefTable::get(void*) const+332 [0x40b984bc]
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108):   at dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+80 [0x40bb9c4d]
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108):   at dvmCallMethodA(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, jvalue const*)+132 [0x40bcfed5]
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108):   at ???+308051 [0x40bbb353]
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108):   at ???+39424 [0x58ebaa00]
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108): 
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108): =================================================================
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108): used by your application.
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108): =================================================================
09-02 17:16:08.176 E/mono-rt (11108): 
09-02 17:16:08.176 F/libc    (11108): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 11145 (anPatrika.Droid)
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access something that has been garbage collected. Can you post some code?

Comment: Its a huge project, I'm doing too many things at startup. So cant really post the code.

Comment: Besides, it stopped doing that after I installed the app in release mode.